# How can I use swift in Terminal?

Tags: xcode, swift, terminal, read-eval-print-loop

I read [What's new in Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). The article introduces some new feature about Xcode 6, and it says:

> Command Line
>
> Xcode’s debugger includes an interactive version of the Swift language, known as the REPL (Read-Eval-Print-Loop). Use Swift syntax to evaluate and interact with your running app or write new code in a script-like environment. The REPL is available from within LLDB in Xcode’s console, or from Terminal.

I want to know how to get the REPL?

Comment: Here is an article I wrote, about this. https://medium.com/swift-programming/1-learn-swift-by-running-scripts-73fdf8507f4b

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

then you can do one of these:

```
xcrun swift 
lldb --repl
```

As of Xcode 6.1 - typing `swift` in the terminal launches the REPL as well.

Comment: ...and to quit, type `Ctrl`+`d`.

Answer (score 56):

Alternatively, if you don't want to mess up your current dev environment, you can just run:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
```

Comment: Or, you could even take this one step further and add this to your `~/.bash_profile`: `alias swift="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift"
`

Comment: To be able to use the OS X SDK you have to specify the path to it as well: `/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk`

Comment: Thanks for the idea David. I added that to the profile, but I keep getting No such file or directory, even though it is right there, and the permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 mark2  admin  33557440 31 May 14:43 swift`. I'm not that strong in unit. Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: Using `xcrun --find swift` to get the path is going to be much more future proof

Comment: `xcrun --toolchain com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3 swift` is way more better. Origin answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36254848/5768974

Answer (score 47):

Step 1: Open Terminal
Step 2: Type "swift"
Step 3: There's no step 3

Example:

```
GoldCoast:~ macmark$ swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> println("Hello, world")
Hello, world
  2> var myVariable = 42
myVariable: Int = 42
  3> myVariable = 50
  4> let myConstant = 42
myConstant: Int = 42
  5> println(myVariable)
50
  6> let label = "The width is "
label: String = "The width is "
  7> let width = 94
width: Int = 94
  8> let widthLabel = label + String(width)
widthLabel: String = "The width is 94"
  9> :exit

GoldCoast:~ macmark$
```

Comment: Although you can continue to use `xcrun swift`, from Swift 2.1 onwards you can simply run `swift` from the command-line.

Comment: My example is from Swift 1.0 in July 2014. It was working without xcrun since ever for me.

Comment: Now you need to type `swift repl`

Answer (score 22):

In Xcode 6.1.1 with Command Line Tools installed you can execute scripts by referencing directly to `/usr/bin/swift` the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

let variable: String = "string"
print("Test \(variable)")
```

Comment: Confirm this to be working with swift 2.1.1 (xcode 7.2 install)

Comment: Anyone who wanna play with Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8 should not miss http://stackoverflow.com/a/36254848/1298043

Comment: this works great — and integrates swift nicely with the bash shell way of using scripts. just need to remember to do a chmod +x on the file and you can execute swift script from anywhere with: ./myswiftscript.swift

Answer (score 15):

In the same fashion as running Swift from the Terminal, you can also execute scripts.
Just use the following shebang, and run your script. ([As per Chris Lattner](https://twitter.com/clattner_llvm/status/474593140511211520), creator of Swift)

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift -i
```

Comment: As per XCode 6 Beta 5 the `-i` flag has been removed and will lead to an error. Just let it go and use `#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift` instead.

Comment: Anyone who wanna play with Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8 should not miss http://stackoverflow.com/a/36254848/1298043

Answer (score 10):

If any one cares a simple Swift script shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun --sdk macosx swift
```

---

If specific target version is required

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun --sdk macosx swift -target x86_64-macosx10.11
```

---

If specific toolchain is required (like you want to use Swift 2.3 but you are using Xcode 8)

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun --toolchain com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3 --sdk macosx swift -target x86_64-macosx10.11
```

---

If you want to use Swift 2.2 in your Xcode 7.3.1, let's assume Xcode 7.3.1 is located at `/Applications/Xcode7.app`

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode7.app/
xcrun --sdk macosx swift
```

from now on the default active developer directory changed, you can check that using:

```
xcode-select -p
```

---

If you want to use snapshots provided by [Swift.org](https://swift.org/download), you should not miss [Installation here](https://swift.org/download/#using-downloads).

---

as first answered by me in [Run swift script from Xcode iOS project as build phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981724/run-swift-script-from-xcode-ios-project-as-build-phase/36248410#36248410)

Answer (score 8):

** update as of xcode6 beta 4 **

this can also be done on xcode preferences. simply go to xcode -> preferences -> locations.

for command line tools simply select the version you want from drop down list options, refer picture below. (swift requires path to be xcode6's path).

[image: command line tools screen]

I will leave my previous answer below as well.

---

what Kaan said and you can also use an apple script to make simple application so you can use it to switch back and forth.

open apple script > paste this below code & export it as an application so with just one click you can switch to default path or beta path (to use swift)

```
set xcode6Path to "xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer"
set xcodeDefaultPath to "xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

display dialog "set xcode sdk path to " buttons {"xcode 6", "default"} default button 1
copy result as list to {buttonPressed}
if buttonPressed is "default" then
    try
        do shell script xcodeDefaultPath with administrator privileges
    end try
else
    try
        do shell script xcode6Path with administrator privileges
    end try
end if
```

then run > `xcrun swift`

**disclaimer**

1. the script assumes you have both xcode6-beta & xcode5 installed.
2. if you're a new developer who's trying out **only** xcode6beta you will not need any script or setting path manually. simply run `xcrun swift` as the path is already set for you.
3. when xcode6 is finally released you will need to reset your path back to **default** from this simple app and never use it again.

Comment: I had XCode 5 installed and have now "updated" (=replaced) to XCode 6. Is there a way to bring back 5.x now? With this solution?

Comment: what do you mean bring back 5.x ? xcode6 GM or appstore release will replace xcode5.

Answer (score 6):

After installing the official Xcode 6.1 release, there is a `swift` command in `/usr/bin/swift`.

Bear in mind that if you have a Python different from the Apple-supplied Python in the path, `swift` can fail with `ImportError: No module named site`. In that case, make sure that you do `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin` before calling `swift`.

Answer (score 5):

The xcrun command will use the DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable to override the currently selected Xcode installation (as set with xcode-select).  You can use that to construct a single command that'll run swift on the command line and put you in the REPL.  That looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/env DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer xcrun swift
```

and you can alias that to just 'swift':

```
alias swift="/usr/bin/env DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer xcrun swift"
```

As an interesting side note, you can use the same kind of invocation to run a swift script just like you'd use bash or python by adding a -i:

```
#!/usr/bin/env DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer xcrun swift -i

println("Hello World!")
```

Of course, once Xcode 6 is released officially and you switch to that as your default developer tools, you can drop the DEVELOPER_DIR=.. bits and just use "xcrun swift".

Answer (score 4):

make sure you install **xcode 6.0** ,but not **6.1**

If you get an error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: the SDK 'MacOSX10.9.sdk' does not support Swift
```

just run

```
xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator8.0 swift
```

or you can

```
export SDKROOT="iphonesimulator8.0"
```

and then

```
xcrun swift
```

Use "`xcodebuild -showsdks`" to list the available SDK names.

if you install **xcode 6.1**,just

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/*your-Xcode-6.1-path.app*/Contents/Developer
xcrun swift
```

Answer (score 2):

For XCode6, run these commands:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

$ xcrun swift
```

If you get an error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: the SDK 'MacOSX10.9.sdk' does not support Swift
```

try:

```
xcrun swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

open Terminal,

$`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer`

**Notice:** The `Xcode6-Beta6.app` should be replaced to appropriate version you installed

Then put this line `alias swift='xcrun swift'` to `~/.bash_profile`

And,

$`source ~/.bash_profile`

$`swift`

There you go!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Swift REPL(Read Eval Print Loop).

Developers familiar with interpreted languages will feel comfortable in this command-line environment, and even experienced developers will find a few unique features

Launch Terminal.app and type swift and press enter. You’ll then be in the Swift REPL.

```
        1> print("Hello Swift REPL")
     Hello Swift REPL
        2> 10 + 20
     $R0: Int = 30
        3> var name = "Yogendra Singh"
     name: String = "Yogendra Singh"
        4> print(name)
     Yogendra Singh
        5>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Terminal type (I verified this works with Swift version 5.7.2):

```
swift repl
```