# Is this a bug in the book "The Swift Programming Language"

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
struct Bank {
    static var coinsInBank = 10_000
    static func vendCoins(var numberOfCoinsToVend: Int) -> Int {
        numberOfCoinsToVend = min(numberOfCoinsToVend, coinsInBank)
        coinsInBank -= numberOfCoinsToVend
        return numberOfCoinsToVend
    }
    static func receiveCoins(coins: Int) {
        coinsInBank += coins
    }
}

class Player {
    var coinsInPurse: Int
    init(coins: Int) {
        coinsInPurse = Bank.vendCoins(coins)
    }
    func winCoins(coins: Int) {
        coinsInPurse += Bank.vendCoins(coins)
    }
    deinit {
        Bank.receiveCoins(coinsInPurse)
    }
}

var playerOne: Player? = Player(coins: 100)
println("A new player has joined the game with \(playerOne!.coinsInPurse) coins")
// prints "A new player has joined the game with 100 coins"
println("There are now \(Bank.coinsInBank) coins left in the bank")
// prints "There are now 9900 coins left in the bank"

playerOne!.winCoins(2_000)
println("PlayerOne won 2000 coins & now has \(playerOne!.coinsInPurse) coins")
// prints "PlayerOne won 2000 coins & now has 2100 coins"
println("The bank now only has \(Bank.coinsInBank) coins left")
// prints "The bank now only has 7900 coins left"

playerOne = nil
println("PlayerOne has left the game")
// prints "PlayerOne has left the game"
println("The bank now has \(Bank.coinsInBank) coins")
// prints "The bank now has 7900 coins"
```

In the last line, my result is 7900, but the book says the result should be 10000.
Are there any typo in my code, or it is a bug of the book? If it is, how should I reset the coinsInBank for another player?
Thank you!

Comment: No, this is how playground works. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24363716/988769

Comment: @Wei, can you add instrumentation to the deinitializer to verify it actually runs? Maybe you have a reference to `playerOne` still alive somewhere?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, thank you! That is my whole code. I believe Kreiri is correct.