# How to print to console using a Swift playground?

Tags: xcode, swift

I can see the Assistant Editor, but using println() doesn't print anything to the console, even `println("hello world")` doesn't print anything!

here is a sample code (am not concerned with memory leaks)

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        println("\(name) is being initialized")
    }
    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}

var reference1: Person?
var reference2: Person?
var reference3: Person?

reference1 = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
reference2 = reference1
reference3 = reference1

reference1 = nil
reference2 = nil
reference3 = nil
```

here is a snapshot

[image]

is it just an Xcode 6 beta 2 problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory leaks in the swift playground / deinit{} not called consistently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021340/memory-leaks-in-the-swift-playground-deinit-not-called-consistently)

Comment: NO no no, am not concerned with memory leaks, this was just a fancy sample code, `println()` doesn't work for me on xcode 6 beta 2!

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work for me either. Works fine in REPL though. You should raise a bug with Apple.

Comment: that's what I was thinking @AshleyMills thanks

Comment: Try to click on the "Console Output" rectangle, for me the console is initially collapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because Xcode 6 is in beta. Various things within the playground fail intermittently, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

When I try that in playground (exact copy & paste) I **do** see the println from the init being printed. You won't see the deinit because it won't actually be called in the playground.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021340/memory-leaks-in-the-swift-playground-deinit-not-called-consistently) question/answer.

Comment: the deinitializer would be called after `reference3 = nil`, this just a sample code, even `println"hello world!"` doesn't work for me, what is the problem?