# Xcode playground compilation flow

Tags: swift, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, swift-playground

I would like to know about the flow of compilation in xcode's playground. I understand it will be same as done in Xcode but as per the output of playground its confusing.

```
import UIKit
// ARC
class Student {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("\(name) is being initialized")
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}

var reference1: Student?
var reference2: Student?
var reference3: Student?

reference1 = Student(name: "John Appleseed")
reference2 = reference1
reference3 = reference1

reference1 = nil
reference2 = nil
reference3 = nil

//Strong reference cycle

class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
    var apartment: Apartment?
    deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class Apartment {
    let unit: String
    init(unit: String) { self.unit = unit }
    weak var tenant: Person?
    deinit { print("Apartment \(unit) is being deinitialized") }
}

var john: Person?
var unit4A: Apartment?

john = Person(name: "John Clair")
unit4A = Apartment(unit: "4A")

john!.apartment = unit4A
unit4A!.tenant = john

john = nil
unit4A = nil
```

**Output**:-

```
John Appleseed is being initialized
John Clair is being deinitialized
Apartment 4A is being deinitialized
John Appleseed is being deinitialized
```

> John Appleseed is being deinitialized

should print before

> John Clair is being deinitialized

As `reference3 = nil` will call deinit method of class `Student` and `John Appleseed is being deinitialized` should get printed and after that `john = nil` will call deinit method of `Person` class and `John Clair is being deinitialized` should get printed

**Note**:- init method of class Person and Apartment is not printing anything in the above shown example

Comment: This works fine in ios app, may be you can file a bug for playground

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363384/deinit-method-is-never-called-swift-playground) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021340/memory-leaks-in-the-swift-playground-deinit-not-called-consistently)

Comment: @InderKumar thanks for the suggestion. I'll file a bug and post the answer here whenever get any response from apple.