# Swift scope of ignored return value?

Tags: swift, scope, return-value, scoping

I have a function similar to the following

```
class Bar {
  deinit {
    print("Do some cleanup")
  }
}

func foo() -> Bar {
  return Bar()
}
```

The scope of `Bar` is clear when calling it like this:

```
func useFoo() {
    let bar = foo()
    runFunctionA()
    // bar goes out of scope: "Do some cleanup" is printed
}
```

However, what happens when the return value is ignored, **will it go immediately out of scope?**

```
func useFoo() {
    let _ = foo()
    // "Do some cleanup" is printed here?
    runFunctionA()
    // "Do some cleanup" is printed here?
}
```

Also, **does it make a difference if `let _ = foo()` is used or only `_ = foo()`?**

Comment: I believe the lifetime of the `Bar` instance is unspecified in both cases (it could be deallocated before or after `runFunctionA()`). In particular, in the first case, the optimiser is free to notice that `bar` isn't used and deallocate the instance before `runFunctionA()`. This is why we have the `withExtendedLifetime(_:_:)` function – in order to guarantee a given value remains alive for the duration of the closure call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second case, there is no one taking the ownership of returned object and hence ARC releases the object immediately. So, you must see `Do some cleanup`, before `runFunctionA()` call.

Also, `let _ = foo()` is similar to `_ = foo`

Now, you must be thinking what crap I am writing when you must be looking at different results in your playground.

The thing is, playgrounds are not meant for checking memory related code. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021340/memory-leaks-in-the-swift-playground-deinit-not-called-consistently).

If you don't trust me, just check your code in an actual project. I sure did.

**Bar:**

```
class Bar {
    deinit {
        print("Do some cleanup")
    }

    class func foo() -> Bar {
        return Bar()
    }
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        useFoo()
        useFooAgain()
    }
    func useFoo() {
        let bar = Bar.foo()
        print("inside useFoo")
    }
    func useFooAgain() {
        let _ = Bar.foo()
        print("inside useFooAgain")
    }
}
```

**Output:**
inside useFoo
Do some cleanup
Do some cleanup
inside useFooAgain

Comment: Reading my mind with your comment about playgrounds ;) Thanks for the answer! Do you know if this is documented/specified somewhere, or if this is up to the compiler (in the second case, I guess the first case is clear)?

Comment: @JanRüegg: I was checking for the official statement, but have not found so far. If I remember correctly, in earlier versions of swift , there was only let _ = available and they added only _ later. It is not making any difference for deinit call though (It is definitely acting weird in playground). Let us dig deeper. If i found something, I will update the answer.