# Change one variable via terminal

Tags: ios, swift

Is possible to change one variable via terminal, please?

In Test.swift have

```
var index: Int = 0
```

and I need to call command from terminal to change it.

I cant find something about this.

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/27902291/5327882

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change variables value while debugging with LLVM in XCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907387/how-to-change-variables-value-while-debugging-with-llvm-in-xcode)