# Run Swift script periodically

Tags: swift, scheduled-tasks

I'm writing Swift script and want to run it automatically. For example, I want my script to clean Downloads folder every week or on schedule. How I can do it?

Comment: Wouldn't be a *real* script language (bash, python, AppleScript) the better choice?

Comment: I really love Swift and want to use it for these tasks

Comment: For scheduling take a look at `launchd` (agent)

Comment: There's nothing swift-specific to this question. It's a duplicate of questions in other stacks, and not on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to be able to run swift from terminal, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011120/how-can-i-use-swift-in-terminal)
Then you can create an cron task to execute it periodically.

(But I think Swift is not a good choice for this kind of job)